# Additional jars from Resource Editor different from LWUIT 1.5 example apps

Tags: netbeans, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I just realized that the Resource Editor still generates the old additional jars with creating the Netbeans project.
 For example: `IO.jar`, `IO_SE.jar`, `UI.jar`, `UI_RIM_Touch.jar` instead of `LWUIT_MIDP.jar`, `MIDP_IO.jar`, `LWUIT_Blackberry_4_7_OrNewer.jar` like used in the example apps in the `LWUIT 1.5` download.

Is this intentional? If yes, do I have to remove the ones auto generated and add the newer jars when working on my project in `net-beans`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR's should generally be updated but they aren't necessarily identical since they are generated by a different build process. We will resolve this in the [Codename One designer tool](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the jars generated by the Resource Editor are updated. I'm working with it, and I got no problems in MIDP projects, but is possible that the UI_RIM is out of date because my BB projects don't start.

Comment: Yes MIDP works just fine, its the BB builds am tearing my hair out over, especially in terms of the network connections errors.

Comment: Oh, I have the same issue. Can it be resolved with LWUIT_Blackberry_4_7_OrNewer.jar? I'm going to try with this.

Comment: Let me know your outcome please. And your netbeans version, so i can download it and do the same. I use 6.9. Thanks

Comment: One thing, are you using `HttpConnection`? the URL must finish with ";deviceside=true"

Comment: thanks but I can't use `deviceside` mainly because I am not developing for Blackberry alone. Unless there was a way to detect the build version and add it. Thanks