# LWUIT ConnectionRequest: Bad Request on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, lwuit

My lwuit application is working fine on Blackberry Simulator while on device the application installs successfully, starts normally, but where am having issues is on network connection. Trying to access network I get 400 Bad Request message. I don't no what am doing wrong, my network connection code is as below:

```
public ConnectionRequest prepareConnection(String page, String progressMsg, final int request)
{
    final ConnectionRequest conR = new ConnectionRequest()
    {
        public void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException  {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int ch;
            while((ch=input.read()) != -1)
                sb.append((char)ch);

            httpResponse(sb.toString().trim(), request);
        }
    };

    conR.setUrl(NetworkHandler.getURL()+page);
    conR.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    Progress progress = new Progress(progressMsg, conR)
    {
        public void actionCommand(Command command)
        {
            if(command.getCommandName().equals("Cancel"))
                conR.kill();
        }
    };
    conR.setDisposeOnCompletion(progress);

    return conR;
}

private void login(String code)
{
    Container container = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();

    if(!validateLogin(container))
    {
        showDialogMessage("Alert", "Please enter your user name and password!");
        return;
    }
    NetworkManager.getInstance().start();

    ConnectionRequest conR = prepareConnection(NetworkHandler.LOGIN_PAGE, "Authenticating...", RequestType.LOGIN);
    Dialog dialog = conR.getDisposeOnCompletion();

    conR.setPost(true);
    conR.addArgument("u", getFieldValue(findTxtUserName(container)));
    conR.addArgument("p", getFieldValue(findTxtPassword(container)));
    conR.addArgument("c", code);

    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(conR);
    dialog.show();
}

public void onLoginForm_BtnLoginAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
      login("");
}
```

Please I want you guys to help me out. 
Thanks in Advance.

The login me

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates a problem in APN configuration on the device. Normally Blackberry app's workaround incorrect APN configurations automatically which is a pretty difficult thing to do. [CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/) does that seamlessly but LWUIT does not.

Comment: @shaialmong, thanks for ur reply. I don't think if APN is the issue because other apps are working fine, connecting to network on the devices i've tested it on. In my country, network operators configure that automatically. About CodenameOne, from what I saw on their website, it seem that the project is not out yet.

Comment: CodenameOne will be out in public beta in the first week of March. The browser has a separate definition for APN so it might work while the application fails. Did you check other device types etc.

Comment: have not tested it on other device type, we have midlet version for other java enabled mobile devices. we wanted the lwuit version to be for blackberry only. can lwuit project be converted to CodenameOne project? I will test it on over devices as you suggested.

Comment: Converting to Codename One requires some work due to different package structure/API & lifecycle.

Comment: I have finally got it working, helped by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9030639/774440) post. I was using Resource Editor generated jars now changed them (UI_RIM_Touch.jar and UI_RIM.jar) to LWUIT_Blackberry_4_7_OrNewer.jar, and it app is now connecting to the Internet. Thanks for your assistance.